# How to convert a list item to a vector name for another list item

Tags: r, list, dataframe

So I have this list (I4);

```
paste(I4)
[1] "d2_cont_v1.xlsx" "d2_cont_v2.xlsx" "d2_cont_v3.xlsx" "d3_cont_v1.xlsx" "d3_cont_v2.xlsx" "d3_cont_v3.xlsx"
 [7] "gfp_v1.xlsx"     "gfp_v2.xlsx"     "gfp_v3.xlsx"     "mu_v1.xlsx"      "mu_v2.xlsx"      "mu_v3.xlsx"     
[13] "wt_v1.xlsx"      "wt_v2.xlsx"      "wt_v3.xlsx"
```

and another list (Inj4CACNA) which is a list of 15 data frames. I am converting the first item in the 'Inj4CACNA' list to a standalone data frame. Then, I want to label this first data frame to be a vector that has the same name as the first item in the "I4" list. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do this.

(The eventual goal is to output csv files of each of these 15 data frames with these names, and .xlsx will be removed too)

Obviously I could just copy and paste this myself but I have lots of files I need to do similar things with so want to do it more efficiently.

I know that I can make my standalone data frame from Inj4CACNA by doing;

```
as.data.frame(Inj4CACNA[[1]])
```

but I don't understand how to write a command that would turn a list item into a vector *name*.

I know to create a vector from a list item I can use

```
vectorname = unlist(I4[1])
```

or to paste the list item as characters

```
paste(I4[1])
```

But I don't know how to apply it in the way I want. Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured it out! For anyone curious;

```
vector = unlist(I4[1])
x = as.data.frame(Inj4CACNA[1])
assign(vector, x)
```